# What do colour codes mean in Isabelle/jEdit?

Tags: isabelle, jedit

What do the colour codes mean in Isabelle/jEdit? I could not find their description in the [Isabelle/jEdit manual](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/hvg/Isabelle/dist/doc/jedit.pdf). The only thing it writes is

> Prover feedback works via colors, boxes, squiggly underline, hyper-
>   links, popup windows, icons, clickable output — all based on semantic
>   markup produced by Isabelle in the background.

Colours are used as proof script background and on a vertical bar beside the scrollbar.

Could you point to some documentation or explain it here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see their names and change them in "Plugins/Plugin Options" and then "Isabelle/Rendering". The names give a relatively clear explanation, and you can refer to the manuals from the terms used in the names.

There is a lot of colors so I won't describe them all.
For the most important **default** colors:

Logic:

- blue : free variable
- green : bound variable
- orange : skolem constant ("free" variables existentially "quantified")
- cyan : syntax (not a variable or a constant, like `case` or `if`)

Isar Keywords:

- sky blue : commands (like `lemma`, `proof` or `have`)
- red : tactic-style commands (like `apply`, `done` or `prefer`)
- turquoise : statements (like `where`, `fixes`, `shows` or `and`)

Messages highlighting in output:

- red : error
- yellow : warning
- light blue : info

Highlighting in editor:

- red : error
- light yellow : current line
- gray : quoted text (logic and types)
- light gray : comment and formal text (introduced with `text` or `section`)
- purple : running process on the command (also shown on the right)
- pink : unprocessed (outdated) command (also shown on the right)

In general, an underlined command displays a message in the output (possibly associated with an icon and a box on the right). More specifically:

Icons, [boxes] and {in text}:

- red exclamation mark [red box] {squiggly red underline} : error
- orange exclamation mark [orange box] {squiggly orange underline} : warning
- blue i {squiggly blue underline}: information (often provided by automatic tools)
- {squiggly gray underline} : the command shows a message in the output
- {red text} : comment (like `(* This is a comment *)`)